# Issues using pattern matching with servant-client

Tags: haskell, servant

In the [Servant docs](http://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/Client.html), we have the following api:

```
type API = "position" :> Capture "x" Int :> Capture "y" Int :> Get '[JSON] Position
      :<|> "hello" :> QueryParam "name" String :> Get '[JSON] HelloMessage
      :<|> "marketing" :> ReqBody '[JSON] ClientInfo :> Post '[JSON] Email
```

and we can define client functions like so:

```
api :: Proxy API
api = Proxy

position :<|> hello :<|> marketing = client api
```

If our api type instead looked like:

```
type API = QueryParam "test" Int :> (
    "position" :> Capture "x" Int :> Capture "y" Int :> Get '[JSON] Position
      :<|> "hello" :> QueryParam "name" String :> Get '[JSON] HelloMessage
      :<|> "marketing" :> ReqBody '[JSON] ClientInfo :> Post '[JSON] Email)
```

which is identical to the original api but with an additional "test" query parameter for all endpoints, how would we obtain our client functions? I have tried several variants of pattern matching, but to no avail.

If all else, fails, the "test" query parameter could be repeated in the api type for each endpoint, but this is Haskell, we try to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Servant API definitions live at the type level. If we want to manipulate them, we need something like a function that transforms types (not values, types themselves) into other types.

The closest thing to such a type-level function in Haskell is called a [closed type family](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#closed-type-families):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family PrependParam api where
    PrependParam (a :<|> b) = PrependParam a :<|> PrependParam b
    PrependParam leaf = QueryParam "test" Int :> leaf

type API' = PrependParam API
```

`:<|>` separates routes, while `:>` separates components within a route. We are mapping over the tree of routes and adding a prefix to each one.

We can check that it works from *ghci*, using the `kind!`command:

```
ghci> :kind! API'
API' :: *
= (QueryParam "test" Int
   :> ("position"
       :> (Capture "x" Int :> (Capture "y" Int :> Get '[JSON] Position))))
  :<|> ((QueryParam "test" Int
         :> ("hello"
             :> (QueryParam "name" String :> Get '[JSON] HelloMessage)))
        :<|> (QueryParam "test" Int
              :> ("marketing"
                  :> (ReqBody '[JSON] ClientInfo :> Post '[JSON] Email))))
```

Comment: That was a very fast answer, thank you very much. The only thing I don't like about this method is that it spreads out the definition of the `API` type, but it does do what it is meant to do, and can be generalised for more complex stuff.